# Chart.js: Is it possible to get the label of a dataset in a stacked bargraph on clicking it?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to get the name of the label associated with the dataset in a stacked bar graph when that particular dataset's stack is clicked on.

This is my code:

```
    var dataPack1 = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500];
    var dataPack2 = [150, 450, 350, 250, 150];
    var dates = ["May 1", "May 2", "May 3", "May 4", "May 5"];
    var bar_chart = new Chart(bar_ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: dates,
            datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Bowser',
                data: dataPack1,
                backgroundColor: "grey"                    
            },
            {
                label: 'Mario',
                data: dataPack2,
                backgroundColor: "maroon"
            },
            ]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
              xAxes: [{ 
                stacked: true, 
                gridLines: { display: false },
                }],
              yAxes: [{ 
                stacked: true
                }],
            }, // scales
            onClick: function(evt, element) {
              //var val = element.something such that val is assigned 'Bowser'
            }
        } // options
       }
    );
```

Now, when I click on say, 500, I want a variable, val to get assigned 'Bowser'. Is that possible?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/gwxeLx3n/) is the jsfiddle for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the prototype method [`.getElementAtEvent(e)`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#getelementatevente) to get the element clicked on like so

```
onClick: function(evt, element) {
  var activePoints = bar_chart.getElementAtEvent(evt);
  console.log(activePoints[0]._model.datasetLabel);
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/hohoda34/)

Or you can attach it as an event handler on the chart element

```
bar_ctx.onclick = function(evt) {
  var activePoints = bar_chart.getElementAtEvent(evt);
  console.log(activePoints[0]._model.datasetLabel);
};
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/5561z8h8/)